# How can jurisdiction be limited if platform does not provide geoblocking?

Tags: international, multiple-jurisdiction

If we are allowed to upload content on to a site but the site does not provide any way to georestrict it, are we still capable of stopping countries we do not target from enforcing or claiming [extraterritorial jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterritorial_jurisdiction) on the fully original educational content.

Assume India is the home jurisdiction.

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: They can be held liable or convicted of crimes under some country's laws. Whether or not that legal judgment can be enforced is an entirely different question. For a criminal conviction there needs to be an arrest by that country (not necessarily lawful where made) or extradition. To enforce a money judgment, the country imposing the judgment has to have the ability to seize assets of the defendant or some other country has to recognize and enforce that judgment. Sometimes those things are possible, sometimes they aren't.

Comment: Could you please state how ? For example some country say. gives imprisonment for using the word <any word you use < >> and can they forcefuly imprison you or cease your assets ?

Comment: To imprison you, they need to arrest you or convince some other country to arrest you and extradite you. To seize your assets, they need to be able to find assets that they can control somehow. Sometimes that's easy to accomplish, and sometimes it is hard to do. See my answer at https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60640/which-countrys-jurisdiction-applies-on-youtube-channels/60642#60642

Answer (score 6):

**You cannot stop the claim.**

But the good news is that claims of jurisdiction by many countries are routinely ignored by many other countries. So enforcement attempts might fall short.

- I've written things here that might get me into real trouble with the authorities of North Korea if I ever traveled there and if they were able to match my real-world identity with this account. But I don't plan to travel there.
- Likewise, before I went to Turkey I should probably review what I've written about their government, and then wonder if it is worth the risk. Probably yes, it wasn't *very* incendiary.
- But my home country and those I tend to visit (if there is no pandemic ongoing) would not extradite me for what I wrote.